# BA910 cancelled - was it extraordinary circumstances?

Tags: cancellations, lhr, british-airways, ec261

I was scheduled to fly on BA910 today (12/12/2022) and it was cancelled. No reason was provided for why and I was informed of the cancellation this morning. I was rebooked onto a flight leaving tomorrow (13/12/2022) after speaking to BA over the phone. I understand that if the cancellation reasons are deemed to be due to "extraordinary circumstances", then I am not entitled to any compensation.

It did snow in London last night but my flight was scheduled for 15:25 and there was no snow for many hours leading up to this. Several other flights, including a BA flight to the same destination 45 minutes before mine, did take off.

What are the realistic chances of getting compensated for this and are there any specific things to be aware of when making the claim? I am able to fill out the compensation claim on the BA website.

Comment: Have you contacted the airline? What have they said?

Comment: Both yesterday's flight and today's one are cancelled ([FR24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ba910)), I don't believe extraordinary circumstances, but you need to know what the airline has to say

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: what makes you think that the airline will answer and also answer truthfully ? Airlines are highly incentivized to declare everything "extraordinary circumstances"

Comment: @Hilmar Yeah, I know, very well, but to do anything, you need to know what the airline has to say about that, you must cast your complaint to them before, if wanted, casting a complaint to the relevant authority

Comment: Note: the first answer is always no. Just keep asking. They must tell you what "extraordinary circumstances" are. Ask them explicitly, and stress about "extraordinary": ask how often they used such excuse.

Comment: Although you may not agree that it was extraordinary circumstances, the UK media was full of reports about 00s of cancelled flights due to the weather eg https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/1708261/airport-Ryanair-stansted-gatwick-heavy-snowfall-met-office-uk-weather-latest-news-ont BA should still respond to you however